# Save a Theme error message on windows 10

Tags: themes, windows-10-v1709

This is the second time in a month or so I've had this happen, and out of nowhere it pops up.

[image: save a theme error pop up]

Googling gets me no proper answer answer. On [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/unprompted-save-a-theme-error-in-windows-10/2ccf61dc-4faf-4e9e-9a0e-35722c38ee00), I've found that many users have had this issue, but not sure if they were all on Windows 10.

I did the sfc/scannow as asked in it. The result is "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." I did the DISM tests and still found no errors.

I could try disabling syncing of windows theme, as suggested by a user, and it has helped many users apparently, but I want my sync to work, not disable it. Also, I do not know for sure if at all that is the actual issue.

I have windows 10 64 bit version 1709 (16299.192) running on a samsung laptop np550p5c with so far no new updates showing up in the settings page.

Comment: What happens when you click 'Yes'?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 If I recall correctly, nothing happens on clicking anything.

Comment: So when this happens, the theme is already saved?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I do not know what triggers the error message. I do not know about the workings of the theme settings.

Comment: Have you tried to disable syncing, save the theme in the Theme Settings, then re-enable syncing?

Comment: Same issue on Windows 10 v.1803

Comment: I too have this problem.  I'm on build 16299.492 and the issue still occurs.

Comment: This message means just what it says - a file is missing from your theme, which is why it appears while syncing. This might relate to the screen-saver, so pops up after some period of inactivity. Try setting your screen-saver to "None" and see if the error disappears. Consider deleting your theme (in `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes` if you can't from Settings), re-downloading it (even if from Microsoft) and re-installing.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I didn't really have a specific theme applied.  At least not on purpose.  I read your links, and have since re-enabled the syncing and just applied a new theme, I expect that will also fix the problem.  Perhaps you should take your comment and make it an answer.

Answer (score 7):

As per the [Cannot find and save a theme error in Windows 10 after update](http://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2018/03/cannot-find-and-save-a-theme-error-in-windows-10-after-update.html) post, I put some potential solutions together with a bit more detail plus another idea.

### Itemized Potential Solutions

> **Note:** *Try any of these individually in no specific order.*

1. From **Settings** -> **Personalization** -> **Themes** you can first simply try to first change whatever theme you have set when the problem occurs to a different theme, and then change it back to the theme you had set—see if that resolves.

   > [image]

---

2. From **Settings** -> **Personalization** -> **Themes** change your current theme to a different theme and then go to `%windir%\Resources\Themes` or `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` or `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` and delete the theme (and correlated folder name too if applicable) you had set when the message popped up.

   If you have trouble deleting either, you may need to [take ownership](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-file-or-folder-manually-in-windows/) accordingly and then delete them after you complete [that procedure](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer).

   > [image]

   Afterwards from **Settings** -> **Personalization** -> **Themes** -> click on **Get more themes in Microsoft Store** and download the theme you deleted and then set your theme back to it again—see if that resolves.

   **Note:** *If your problem theme did not come from the Microsoft Store, simply download it again from where ever you got it from instead, and then set it as your theme again. Consider using a theme from the Microsoft Store though if possible.*

   > [image]

---

3. If the **Background** is set to a **Slideshow** you can go to **Settings** -> **Personalization** -> **Background**, and change the **Background** drop down to a **Picture**—see if that resolves.

   > [image]

---

4. From **Settings** -> **Accounts** -> **Sync your settings**, toggle the **Sync settings** option off and wait a few and then toggle it back on. If that option is not able to be toggled for some reason and grayed out, then in the **Individual sync settings**, toggle the **Theme** option off, wait a few and then toggle it back on—see if that resolves.

   > [image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though that window comes from **SettingSyncHost.exe**.  I have the same problem, and it appears as though it is related to syncing your theme across machines.

If you go to **START**, and type **Sync your settings** you can disable the syncing of your theme.  This resolved the problem on my machine.

Although it doesn't explain the root cause, it does seem to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the author specifically indicated they want to synchronize their Theme settings.

Comment: I set the bounty because I had the same exact problem for months, when I saw this unanswered post I too wanted an answer. Then I stumbled on a way to fix it, once I found the .exe causing the popup. So I answered it.

Comment: Your suggestion was suggested **multiple times**, while it answered *your* question, it doesn’t answer the **authors** question. As evident by the deleted answers that suggested the same solution as you did

Answer (score 2):

This message means just what it says - a file is missing from your theme.
The error will be detected while syncing, but disabling sync only hides
the problem and does not fix it.

As you say that "out of nowhere it pops up", this might relate to the screen-saver
popping up after a period of inactivity.
Try setting your screen-saver to "None" to see if the error disappears.
If it does, re-install or choose another screen-saver.

[image: image1]

---

Otherwise, consider refreshing the theme starting with completely
deleting it either
[using PC Settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028102224/https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/76729-delete-theme-windows-10-a.html#option2) for the current user :

[image: image1]

---

Or, if that does not work, then
[delete through File Explorer for all users](https://web.archive.org/web/20171028102224/https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/76729-delete-theme-windows-10-a.html#option4) :

[image: image2]

You might need to
[Change the owner of the .theme file](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206155439/http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3587-owner-files-folders-change-windows-10-a.html) :

[image: image3]
<sub>(source: [tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/10526d1485949264t-change-owner-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-10-a-change_owner_advanced_security_settings-3.jpg))</sub>

Or to
[Change the permissions of the .theme file you want to delete](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/permissions-allow-or-deny-access-to-users-and-groups-in-windows-8.2815/) :

[image: image4]

After deletion, re-download the theme, even if it is from Microsoft,
and re-install.
If the error message returns, then the theme itself is broken and you should
choose another.

Answer (score -1):

I have an idea of what that error could display.

Did you move one of the background files (I.e. Background.jpg) to another folder recently? Perhaps setting up a new theme with the same settings might help